# Reference Lat/Lon VRT files in Data.VRT for GDALTranslaste

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff

As a follow up to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137331/georeferencing-uneven-irregularly-gridded-rasters)

I have three rasters:

- lat.tif with latitude values
- lon.tif with longitude values
- data.tif with data values (corresponding to the lat/lon values)

From there I have created lat.vrt,lon.vrt, and data.vrt files.

How can I reference the two lat.vrt and lon.vrt files inside the data.vrt?

In reference to the previous question: How would I go about writing two lat/lon .vrt files "in a geoarrays in the data.vrt metadata"?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out!

I added the following to the data.vrt file to reference both the lat.vrt and lon.vrt. If it cannot find the lat.vrt/lon.vrt add the path:

```
<Metadata domain="GEOLOCATION">
      <MDI key="X_DATASET">lon_1.vrt</MDI>
      <MDI key="X_BAND">1</MDI>
      <MDI key="Y_DATASET">lat_1.vrt</MDI>
      <MDI key="Y_BAND">1</MDI>
      <MDI key="PIXEL_OFFSET">0</MDI>
      <MDI key="LINE_OFFSET">0</MDI>
      <MDI key="PIXEL_STEP">1</MDI>
      <MDI key="LINE_STEP">1</MDI>    
 </Metadata>
```